# Integer/Long from excel seen inside (VBA's and c++'s) VARIANT as a double

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll, variant

I have the following c++ code :

```
#include <OAIdl.h> // for VARIANT, BSTR etc

__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall updatevar(VARIANT * x)
{
    double nb = 3.0;
    ++nb;
}
```

with a function doing (almost) nothing (to avoid warnings)

and a .def file :

```
LIBRARY   tmp0
EXPORTS
   updatevar   @1LIBRARY
```

I compile this with visual studio 2013 into a dll that I reference as follows in excel-2013's VBA :

```
Declare Sub updatevar Lib "C:\path\to\thedll.dll" (ByRef x As Variant)
```

and that I use like this :

```
Public Sub DoIt()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C4")
    Dim var As Variant
    var = r.Value
    Call updatevar(var)

End Sub
```

where the 6-cells excel range `B2:C4` contains strings, dates, doubles and *ints/longs*.

I put a breakpoint in c++ code to inspect the variant pointed to that I receive, as remarked that the type of its 6 elements is always rightly resolved  : dates go to a `vt` (variant type `VT_DATE`) equal to 7, doubles to a `vt` (variant type `VT_R8`) equal to 5, strings go to a `vt` (variant type `VT_BSTR`) of 8, except for ints/longs, that are mapped to `VT_R8` and treated as doubles.

At the beginning I thought it was a c++ problem but, already inspecting the range `r` in the VBA code, and its `Value2` field, showed to me that all ints/longs were treated in VBA as `Variant/Double` and not `Variant/Long`, and I have no idea why this is happening.

*Note.* I put `c++` and `dll` tags as the people interested in these tags may also help given the context involving exchanging VARIANT's between c++ and VBA.

*Remark.* "Downcasting" from double to int is not an option, especially as VARIANT is supposed to know about ints/longs (`VT_I4 = 2` and `VT_I4 = 3` do exist.)

Comment: My understanding is that there are no true integers in Excel --- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762316/representation-of-integers-in-excel-2010-vs-excel-2003-c-plugin)